# SP 2010 recovery

Tags: 2010, backup, content-database

I accidentally uninstalled SharePoint 2010 from control panel (Stupid me). Luckily SQL SP database such as content db is available. How to reinstall or recover back ? Help much appreciated.

Comment: How many server in the farm? What service app were configured?  How many webapp?

Answer (score 1):

The key solution for your problem is:

1. Re-install SharePoint and create a brand new web application.
2. Detach the content database via powershell
3. Attach content DB

This will restore the site collections and the associated content from the old content DB.

You can refer the scripts and complete details in the below article:

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628965(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, just to make sure when I install I create a new farm and new db's in SQL right (just like installing new sp infra) ? and then restore content database, anything else apart from this ? will it restore everything ?

Comment: yes its installing a new farm or new SP instance from scratch if you dont have one like test or dev. but if you have one you may reuse and then just restore the sitecollections itself. yes, it will restore everything and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only server

- in the farm then you have to rebuild the farm. As you said, you have
  the Content DBs then it is easy to recover.
- Most important, Clean Uninstall. Remove all the folders on sharepoint path, clean the IIS etc. No left over should be on the server other wise it will cause issue for new install.
- Install the SharePoint on the server( should be same version level as it was before)
- create New Config database.
- Create and Configure new Service Applications
- Create and Configure new Web applications
- Configure authentication, Update the AAM settings, IIS bindings( if any)
- Apply all customization (if any)
- Now attach the Content DB to Web Application.